# Burn a CD from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, com

I have a Silverlight application with a large DataGrid. I have added the ability to export the contents of that DataGrid to Excel, PDF, and several other formats. In my export dialog, I have a checkbox that says "Burn to CD". The reason I'm trying to do this is my user base really wants to be able to export files directly to a CD.

My question is, is this even possible with Silverlight? I think I can do this through COM interop which was unveiled with Silverlight 4. But I know that COM interop is limited to Windows, because of this cross-platform support would be nixed. I guess my questions are:

1. Can I burn to a CD with Silverlight?
2. Is COM Interop "the way" to accomplish this?
3. Is there a way to burn to a CD from Silverlight on the Mac?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM Interop is only possible within Out-Of-Browser mode and with elevated rights. Also COM is Microsoft only so you wont be able to use that with Macintosh.

Maybe you can generate an ISO or ZIP file on the server side, or even on client-side if you'd want and deliver that to the user, that way the user can decide to store it on an USB stick or burn to a CD theirself.